# How to convert from LPVOID to LPBYTE IN C++?

Tags: c++

I have 0x2.txt file, i encrypt its content using xor algorithm,
i use crypt function to enceypt :

```
LPVOID Crypt(HANDLE hFile, DWORD dwFileSize) {
    // allocate buffer for file contents
    LPVOID lpFileBytes = malloc(dwFileSize);
    // read the file into the buffer
    ReadFile(hFile, lpFileBytes, dwFileSize, NULL, NULL);

    // apply XOR encryption
    int i;
    char key[3] = {'*', '~', '#'};
    for (i = 0; i < dwFileSize; i++) {
        *((LPBYTE)lpFileBytes + i) ^= key[i % sizeof(key)];
    }

    return lpFileBytes;
}
```

and i store the bytes for file in LPVOID variable,

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("1.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        // get file size
        DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

        // decrypt and obtain decrypted bytes
        LPVOID lpFileBytes = Crypt(hFile, dwFileSize);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
```

now i want to make a LPBYTE variable to store the values that stored in LPVOID lpFileBytes,

i did something like this:

```
LPBYTE lpBuffer = lpFileBytes;
```

but it gives me this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'LPVOID {aka void*}' to 'LPBYTE {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]|
```

what i want is, store lpFileBytes values in LPBYTE  variable.

Comment: Why don't you just use `LPBYTE` for all your calls and data types in the first place?

Comment: Pretty sure you asked this question before, and the answer is the same as last time, use a cast. `LPBYTE lpBuffer = static_cast<LPBYTE>(lpFileBytes);` but maybe you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @test2312 Strange thing to me is that you were already using a cast here `*((LPBYTE)lpFileBytes + i)`. And the answer Adrian gave is the best one. Don't use `LPVOID` at all.

Comment: And,as this is C++, use `LPBYTE lpFileBytes = new BYTE[dwFileSize];` instead of the `malloc` call.

Comment: `LPBYTE pb = (LPBYTE)lpFileBytes;`